# Why the git rebase HEAD~3 --autosquash does not squash the fixup?

Tags: git

[image]

After running `git rebase HEAD~3 --autosquash` nothing changes...
Why?

Comment: `git rebase -i`: the `-i` part is very important

Comment: 1. it works, you can put this as answer and i will mark it as correct

Comment: 2. and why there is a difference between git rebase HEAD~3 and git rebase HEAD~3 --autosquach (not in the tree, without the --autosquash it says that the branch is up to date but with it, git rebases without any errors, but as i said, nothing is changed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to use the `-i` option with `--autosquash`.  New versions of Git might not require it, but older ones will (and it doesn't hurt).

As to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61565182/why-the-git-rebase-head3-autosquash-does-not-squash-the-fixup?noredirect=1#comment108902115_61565182): rebase is complicated.

In particular, `git rebase` is a front end that parses options and other arguments and then invokes one of several different rebase implementations:

- `git-rebase--am` is the original rebase, dating back to well before even the oldest current Git versions still in use (1.7-era).  It uses `git format-patch` and `git am` and is the least capable (but fastest) rebase.
- `git-rebase--interactive` is the standard backend for all interactive rebases up until Git version 2.13.  It uses `git cherry-pick`.
- `git-rebase--merge` is a variant of non-interactive rebase that uses cherry-pick.  This is the form of rebase you get with `git rebase -m`, `git rebase -s strategy`, or `git rebase -X eXtended-argument`, unless you add an explicit `-i` as well, in which case you get the interactive back end.
- `git-rebase--preserve-merges` is a special purpose back end split off in Git version 2.19.0.  It implements the old style `git rebase -p`.  (The new `git rebase -r` requires the new sequencer-based rebase mentioned below.)
- Starting with Git 2.13 and progressing further through Git 2.19 (when the preserve-merges back end was split off), the interactive rebase backend has grown more capable (and been written less in shell script and more in C), and now uses Git's *sequencer* code, which previously mainly implemented `git cherry-pick` and `git revert`.
- As of Git 2.20, `git-rebase--interactive` no longer exists at all (but `git rebase -i` still does an interactive rebase).  As of Git 2.23, `git-rebase--am` no longer exists as a separate back-end script (but this style of rebase still exists, it's just handled more directly).
- As of Git 2.26, `git rebase` no longer uses the `am` style machinery by default.  (This might mean you don't need a separate `-i` option, but my own Git installations are not this new so I have not tested it.)

The `--autosquash` option requires the use of the interactive back end machinery, and requires that Git generate the list of commits that might be applied so that the code can check for `fixup!` and `squash!` commit subjects.  Use of the interactive machinery in particular disables the "already up to date" check.

Answer (score 0):

2020:

> Be sure to use the `-i` option with `--autosquash`

2023:

Not anymore! With Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), "[`git rebase --autosquash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f8f87e082798939362410aed587dd22e280913c3/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L590)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---autosquash))</sup> is now enabled for non-interactive rebase, but it is still incompatible with the `apply` backend.

See [commit cb00f52](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb00f524df206f64174840b3f85eb39289e5a038), [commit 297be59](https://github.com/git/git/commit/297be59456f2d27710de01ab88c025241ccb4206), [commit 75cf39b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75cf39b1178f5e6c2830bf3e81521828bb0171ff) (14 Nov 2023) by [Andy Koppe (`akoppecodek`)](https://github.com/akoppecodek).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f8f87e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f8f87e082798939362410aed587dd22e280913c3), 09 Dec 2023)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/297be59456f2d27710de01ab88c025241ccb4206): support --autosquash without -i
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Andy Koppe</sup>

> The [`rebase --autosquash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/297be59456f2d27710de01ab88c025241ccb4206/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L590)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---autosquash))</sup> option is quietly ignored when used without `--interactive` (apart from preventing preemptive fast-forwarding and triggering conflicts with apply backend options).
>
> Change that to support `--autosquash` without `--interactive`, by dropping its restriction to `REBASE_INTERACTIVE_EXCPLICIT` mode.
> When used this way, auto-squashing is done without opening the `todo` list editor.
>
> Drop the `-i` requirement from the `--autosquash` description.

And:

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb00f524df206f64174840b3f85eb39289e5a038): rewrite --(no-)autosquash documentation
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Andy Koppe</sup>

> Rewrite the description of the rebase `--(no-)autosquash` options to try to make it a bit clearer.
> Don't use "the '`...`'" to refer to part of a commit message, mention how `--interactive` can be used to review the `todo` list, and add a bit more detail on commit `--squash`/`amend`.

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cb00f524df206f64174840b3f85eb39289e5a038/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L592-L612):

> Automatically squash commits with specially formatted messages into
> previous commits being rebased.
> If a commit message starts with
> "`squash!` ", "`fixup!` " or "`amend!` ", the remainder of the subject line
> is taken as a commit specifier, which matches a previous commit if it
> matches the subject line or the hash of that commit.
> If no commit
> matches fully, matches of the specifier with the start of commit
> subjects are considered.
>
> In the rebase `todo` list, the actions of squash, fixup and amend commits are
> changed from `pick` to `squash`, `fixup` or `fixup -C`, respectively, and they
> are moved right after the commit they modify.
> The `--interactive` option can
> be used to review and edit the todo list before proceeding.
>
> The recommended way to create commits with squash markers is by using the
> `--squash`, `--fixup`, `--fixup=amend:` or `--fixup=reword:` options of
> [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit), which take the target commit as an argument and
> automatically fill in the subject line of the new commit from that.
>
> Settting configuration variable `rebase.autoSquash` to true enables
> auto-squashing by default for interactive rebase.
> The `--no-autosquash` option can be used to override that setting.